# Calling Curl(ed) json content from Code Igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

This is my function in model

```
<?php
    class Clothes_model extends CI_Model {

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->load->database();
    }

    public function get_clothes()
    {
        $url="http://192.168.0.105/ci/json_source/clothes.php";//clothes.php contain json data
        $data= this->curl->simple_get($url);
        $result = json_decode($data,true);
        return $result;
    }
}
```

This is my controller

```
<?php
class Clothes extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('clothes_model');
    }

    public function view($result)
    {
        $data['clothes_item'] = $this->clothes_model->get_clothes();

        if (empty($data['clothes_item']))
        {
            show_404();
        }

        $data['title'] = $data['clothes_item']['title'];

        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('clothes/view', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }
}
```

When I tried to run I got this error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR in
>   /var/www/ci/application/models/clothes_model.php on line 12

Is there anything wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try changing:

```
this->curl->simple_get($url);
```

to

```
$this->curl->simple_get($url);
```

And make sure your `$this->curl` is valid

Comment: $this->load->library('curl'); is correct? Instead of   $this->load->database();? //model class

Comment: @WayneTun you dont need to load library in model, just load the library in controller, and you can use $this->curl in your model

Comment: dose php5-curl library need to be installed on server?

Comment: @WayneTun yes curl need to be installed on server in order to work

Answer (score 0):

I did like this and works for me

```
    $string=file_get_contents("proj-data/food_query.php"); //place where json file is
    $decoded=json_decode($string,TRUE);
```

Comment: my server was unable to install curl